# Why does flask-testing spawn two test instances?

Tags: python, unit-testing, flask

I want to use the LiveServerTestCase class which is provided by flask-testing to test my flask application in combination with Selenium.

I tried implementing the tests the way described in the flask-testing documentation. But documentation on the LiveServerTestCase is very sparse and I always end up getting two instances of my testcases which are executed at the same time.

I ran my tests through Eclipse and PyCharm with the same behaviour.

How do I have to run/configure my tests to only get one testing instance?

This is how I setup my tests:

```
import unittest
import urllib2
from selenium import webdriver
from CodeLoad import app
from flask_testing import LiveServerTestCase    

class flask_tests(LiveServerTestCase):

    def create_app(self):
        return app

    def setUp(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()

    def tearDown(self):
        self.driver.close()

    def test_0_server_is_up_and_running(self):
        response = urllib2.urlopen(self.get_server_url())
        self.assertEqual(response.code, 200)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Comment: Did you try http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/patterns/appfactories/?

Comment: My problem is not that I'm unable to create multiple instances of my flask app. The problem is that the testing framework executes the tests two times at the same time instead of just executing it once.

Comment: I ran into a similar issue with nose when my test classes were in an __init__ file. Perhaps a similar sort of thing is going on here.

Answer (score 5):

Because of a bug.
https://github.com/jarus/flask-testing/issues/33

Try turning DEBUG off

Comment: I have spent like 3 hours on that.